# send json object or render a view with express route

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pagination

I have two routes: `/news` and `/news-paginate` (I know it is a not good URL but it doesn't matter atm). In the `news` route, I load 5 records from the database and render a populated view. In the `/news-paginate` route, I load other 5 records based on the page number and size sent from the client; this route responds with a JSON object.

**news route**

```
router.get('/news', function (req, res) {

...

  connection.query(queries['news_list'], [language, +pageSize, +offset], function (err, rows) {
      res.render('news', {news: rows});
  });
});
```

**news-paginate route**

```
router.get('/news-paginate', function (req, res) {
  var language = 'RU';
  var pageSize = req.query.pageSize;
  var pageNumber = req.query.pageNumber;
  var offset = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;

  connection.query(queries['news_list'], [language, +pageSize, +offset], function (err, rows) {
    res.json(rows);
  });
});
```

I am concerned about my architecture. Is my approach correct? I have two routes with the same functionality and different responses. Should I somehow combine these two routes into one?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I usually have a single route, in your case `/news` which can receive 2 optional params: `pageSize`, `pageNumber` for your pagination purposes.  If those params don't exists than you will offer the first 5 records. If those params are present than you will start providing the other 5 records and based on the calculated `offset`.

```
router.get('/news/:pageSize?/:pageNumber?', function (req, res) {
  var language = 'RU';
  var pageSize = req.params.pageSize || 5;
  var pageNumber = req.params.pageNumber || 1;
  var offset = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize; // If no params are provided than the offset should be 0

  connection.query(queries['news_list'], [language, +pageSize, +offset], function (err, rows) {
    res.json(rows);
  });
});
```

I am not familiar with optional params in `express routes` but I hope you get the main idea behind the approach.

You can do **ajax** requests to load the extra records after the first 5 records are listed.

I hope this shined a light on the approach.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. The problem is that I have two different responses. One function responds with a json object the other one renders a view.

Comment: aw... I see.. Well in that case 2 routes is the way to go. You could go with one route if you would pass an object instead of rendering a view.